# Has 3D touch to switch apps been removed in iOS11?

Tags: iphone, multi-touch, ios

One of the best uses of 3D touch in my opinion was being able to push on the side of the phone and swipe between apps in a single, fluid movement. However once I updated to iOS11 I noticed that I cannot do it anymore.

I have an iPhone 6s, this is also the case for a friend of mine who has the iPhone 7.

Is there any option to re-enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was [removed](https://www.twitter.com/irace/status/880794987914563585/photo/1) in the first iOS 11 beta and the feature did not ship with the official iOS 11 release.

[Apple has publicly explained a technical limitation caused the tradeoff and that a 11.x release will return this feature](https://daringfireball.net/linked/2017/09/21/ios-11-3d-touch-switcher). No date is given for 3D touch's return.